# Разрешено ли присваивание значения в раздельных блоках always в System Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Начинаю изучать System Verilog. Судя по увиденным мной [примерам](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2pYJ), здесь можно проворачивать штуки наподобие:

```
logic [3:0] a;
always @(posedge reset)
    a <= 0;
always @(posedge clk)
    a <= a + 1'b1;
```

Т.е. выполнять присваивания в различных блоках always.
Однако, когда я пытаюсь синтезировать подобный код в Vivado, получаю ошибку `multiple drivers`, в общем, тоже самое, что сказали бы мне, если бы я писал на обычном Verilog-е.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xороший вопрос

Для тестового стенда нет проблем, и это законно, но вы не можете синтезировать этот код для проектирования реального оборудования. Инструмент Vivado предназначен для использования в FPGA для реализации кодов HDL, поэтому код не может быть синтезирован для FPGA.

В этом случае представьте 4 регистра, которые используются для хранения логики `а`. Регистры запускаются по фронту и идентичны. Как вы, возможно, знаете, все блоки `always` в модуле выполняются параллельно. Когда вы используете переменную внутри блока `always`, которая запускается с положительным фронтом сигнала `clk`, это означает, что регистры, которые используются для хранения этой переменной, запускаются с положительным фронтом сигнала `clk`.

Здесь вы говорите Vivado использовать триггерный регистр `clk` и триггерный `reset` одновременно. Vivado не знает, какой из них выбрать, поэтому выдает ошибку.

Если мы предполагаем, что `reset` выполняется вручную человеком, и если ваш дизайн является синхронным и синхронизированным (как правило, это имеет место в практических аппаратных разработках), вы можете получить что-то подобное (это практично, если ваши часы имеют частоту, превышающую 10 Гц

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
If(reset)
    a <= 0;
else
    a <= a + 1;
end
```

Если вышеприведенное предположение не соответствует действительности и это нормально, даже если для `a` установлено значение 4'b0, пока применяется сигнал «сброса» (не только положительный фронт), тогда:

```
reg [3:0] a_clk;

always @(posedge clk)
    a_clk <= a_clk + 1'b1;

assign a = a_clk & (!reset);
```

Извините за мой плохой русский, было бы неплохо, если бы вы могли отредактировать и исправить мой ответ, чтобы другие русскоязычные могли использовать эти знания